# Modular equations: where did I make a mistake?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to solve the simultaneous congruences
$$\begin{cases} 2x \equiv 4 \mod 8  \\ x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases} $$

My solution:
$$2x \equiv 4 \mod 8 \iff x = 4l + 2 $$
$$x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \iff 4l + 2 \equiv 2 \mod 6 \iff 4l = 6k \iff x = 6k + 2 $$
And the correct answer is: $12n + 2$.
Where did I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

$4l = 6k \iff l = 3n, k = 2n$ so $4l = 6k \iff x = 12n + 2$

Answer (score 2):

$$2x\equiv8\pmod8\iff x\equiv2\pmod4\iff x-2\equiv0$$

and $$x\equiv2\pmod6\iff x-2\equiv0$$

So, lcm$(4,6)\mid(x-2)$

Answer (score 2):

You already know

- $x-2 = 4l$
- $x-2 = 6k$

Therefore, $x-2$ is a multiple of both $4$ and $6$. Then, it must be a multiple of $12$ and we get $x-2 = 12n$.

> $$x=12n+2$$